# Regex, WordPress, and the Search Regex plugin - converting a script to a shortcode

Tags: regex, wordpress, search, replace, search-regex

I am using WordPress and the [Search Regex plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/).

I need to covert several hundred Posts that contain a script which contains a unique Photo album number.

Each script needs to be changed to a shortcode which contains the same Photo album number.

Here is an example:

Search for the script:

```
<tt>%%wppa%%</tt> <tt>%%album=15%%</tt>
```

and replace it with the shortcode:

```
[wppa type="album" album="15"][/wppa]
```

What would I place in the Search field?

and

What would I place in the Replace field?

Comment: Something like Find: `<tt>%%album=([^%]+)%%</tt>` Replace ....

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

```
<tt>%%([^%]+)%%</tt>\s*<tt>%%([^%=]+)=([^%=]+)%%</tt>
```

and this replacement:

```
[$1 type="$2" $2="$3"][/$1]
```

The `$` numbers in the replacement refer to the capture groups: `()`. Overall, it's very simple, with `[^%]+` matching "not `%`", `\s*` matching whitespace, and `[^%=]+` matching "not `%` or `=`".

The plugin uses PCRE, but I'm not sure if the regex needs any adjustments since I don't use the plugin. (It may require escaping the `/` characters.)

Comment: The search `<tt>%%([^%]+)%%</tt>\s*<tt>%%([^%=]+)=([^%=]+)%%</tt>` produced no results

Comment: The search `<tt>%%([^%]+)%%<\/tt>\s*<tt>%%([^%=]+)=([^%=]+)%%<\/tt>` using the escape character `\` produced no results

Comment: The problem I am having is capturing the album number and moving it to replacement.